# No sound on Raspberry Pi Running Kali Linux

Tags: audio, kali

I'm running Kali Linux on my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B and I've had problems from the start. First, PulseAudio wouldn't connect to the server, so I removed it and installed a few packages with different audio and visual programs. I still can't get the audio to work. I can't even get a volume slider up. Can anyone suggest a good program or some fix/workaround for this? 
Thanks

Comment: Check if you have `dtparam=audio=on` in your `/boot/config.txt` file. Also post your `dmesg` output here, it will reveal any hardware/driver problem

Comment: Try: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/406/how-to-enable-the-sound-on-kali-linux

Comment: Why do you need sound on Kali? If you need a system with multimedia capabilities, try Raspbian or OpenElec.